# Collecting hash keys based on values comparison

Tags: ruby

I have a hash like this:

```
h={
  :p1 => [:c1,:c2],
  :p2 => [:c3,:c4],
  :p3 => [:c1,:c5],
  :p4 => [:c3,:c2],
  :p5 => [:c6,:c7]
}
```

I'd like to find a nice Ruby function that returns an array of arrays like this:

```
res=[[:p1,:p3],[:p2,:p4]]
```

Each sub-array is made of hash keys whose first values associated are equal: `:p1` and `:p3` have `:c1` as a starting value, and `:p2` and `:p4` have `:c3`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How's this?

```
h.keys.group_by {|k| h[k][0]}
# => {:c1=>[:p1, :p3], :c3=>[:p2, :p4], :c6=>[:p5]}
```